# On vs At with date and time

Tags: prepositions

This must be a simple question for a native speaker.

I know that we use "on" with dates: `I'll see you on January 1st.`

And we use "at" with times: `I'll see you at 17:30.`

But what preposition has to be used when we speak for date and time:

`I'll see you on January 1st at 17:30.` looks ok.

But what in this case: `It happened on 2014-01-01 17:30.`

Is "on" correct when we are specifying the date and the time?

The date-time comes as a ready text as `2014-01-01 17:30` and I cannot modify it. I can only put text before the date-time string or after it.

Comment: Few native speakers would ever write the date and time like your 4th example. It would almost always be written like your 3rd example (or some variation thereof)

Comment: I need this text in log written from software product. There is an event and a time stamp. I have to put some preposition between them.

Comment: In that case it would be exactly the same as your third example - the construction is the same - `on DATE at TIME`

Comment: I cannot put "at" between the date and time. The time stamp comes as string like:  `2007-04-01 22:00`

Comment: Well, leaving aside the fact that you probably pretty easily could just concatenate 'at' into the timestamp string, `on` would have to do. Considering it's just a log the grammar matters less than the information therein, surely?

Comment: Time of occurrence: 2014-01-01 17:30

Comment: Any reasonably competent person would _understand_ a single preposition, but if you want to be correct about it, two is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use two prepositions. Can you post your comment as an an answer, in order to accept it and close the question. It looks like that this is a specific case with a little meaning out of its context.

Comment: If you really are limited to one preposition I would use 'at', since the date & time as stated is precise to the minute. That requires 'at'.

Comment: @WS2 that was my thought also. Since the time stamp is precised, I thought I should use at.

Comment: `"It happened on "+timeStamp.replace(/ /," at ");`

Comment: But I wouldn't try and make a verb out of 'precise'. It is unnecessary anyway. You could say 'Since the time stamp is specific to the minute', or '...precise to the minute'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking for advice on standard English, but on how to make standard English rules apply in a situation they're not designed for. If there _is_ a standard choice here, the  answer belongs in say a thread in ComputerSE tagged 'vocabulary'.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The construction for your fourth example would be the same as your third:

> on DATE at TIME

While most people would understand it without the AT, it is strictly correct to include it.

Comment: I finally chose a single preposition form with "at". Because the time is the meaningful info. A real example from the software is: `Big Gap of bar 403 at 2007-04-01 20:00.`

Comment: @ElendilTheTall, So is it at `8am 2016-06-06` or is it on `8am 2016-06-06`?

Answer (score 18):

As far as I know from my teaching experiences; you should consider the smallest time unit when using a prep. As follows;
*It happened in 2014*
*It happened on 2014-01-01*
*It happened at 2014-01-01 17:30*
I hope this helps.

Comment: This does make sense, as this defines precision of date-time value - speaking about year, month, day, or exact time.

Answer (score 15):

In computing, the notion of date and time is often amalgamated into a single entity, a datetime.

It may be required that a datetime is presented in a particular format. An example datetime expressed in ISO 8601 may take the form `2019-06-12T14:07:38Z`. The problem is that these standardized datetimes do not naturally blend into English text. Neither `It happened on 2019-06-12T14:07:38Z` nor `It happened at 2019-06-12T14:07:38Z` are standard English.

I would argue that 'at' is the better option since we are referring to a moment in time rather than to a day as 'on' would imply.

Comment: While this is useful information, I don't believe it answers the question from 2014, which was about the difference between using *at* and *on* when using plain language dates and times.

Comment: @Davo Please read the question author's comments. He is coming from a computing background and is asking precisely about the scenario in my answer.

Comment: Like this one: ***I have to put some preposition between them*** ? It's not a question about formatting date time stamps, it's a question about the use of *on* and/or *in* when listing dates and times in plain language.

Comment: @Davo 'I cannot put "at" between the date and time. The time stamp comes as string like: 2007-04-01 22:00' - miroslav-popov

Comment: @GrantZvolský is correct. The time stamp comes as a ready-made text. It would be overkill to parse it, having into account that the exact format is unknown, only to set a preposition.

Comment: Now that this additional information has been incorporated into the question, I concur. However, this does essentially invalidate the answers (including the accepted answer) from 2014.

Comment: I favor "at" to explain some event occurrences. In application logs, the analysis for events requires accuracy to milliseconds (nanoseconds). Can anyone understand my description like this? I found an error log record about our server failed to receive the corresponding response after it sent a query request at 2024-12-22 12:27:38.123, while Wireshark showed TCP retransmission (time-out) around that time point.

Answer (score 7):

You would always use both.

> Let's do something *at* TIME *on* DATE

You *could* abbreviate the "at" out in some circumstances but only when facilitated by grammar and cadence... And even then, it's still implied:

> Shall we meet *on* DATE... around TIME?