# ‘On’ vs. ‘at’ with immutable date-time string

Tags: prepositions, time, dates

I understand that *on* is used for dates and *at* for times, as in [On vs At with date and time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182660/on-vs-at-with-date-and-time). But what can I use when I have a string consists of both a date and a time? The issue is that I can’t change the date-time string to add *at* between the date and the time—so my options are:

> On 19 January 2015 10:53
>   At 19 January 2015 10:53

Which one is the better option?

Comment: How about `at 10:53, 19 January 2015`?

Comment: I can't change the format in this context, only power i got is to either add a word in start or maybe at end

Comment: In that case, assuming this is a list of data, I'd suggest you don't bother at all and leave it as a naked date/time. However, in the linked question, the OP went for *at*. If you **have** to have something, *at* is better because the time trumps the date in terms of granularity.

Comment: How is this not an exact, precise duplicate of the question linked to? The situation is **exactly** the same: a string containing a date and a time is received as input in some software and cannot be changed. A preposition must be chosen. It’s the exact same question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet are you for serious ?

Comment: @CustomizedName Yes. There is absolutely nothing in your question that isn’t precisely the same as in the one you yourself linked to. How is that not a duplicate?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is "Date and Time" (2 words) are same as "DateTime" (1 word) ?

Comment: No, of course not, because ‘DateTime’ is not a word at all. It’s the name of various programming variables. It’s not English, any more than, say, ‘getElementById’ is. That’s completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: either way - you understand what I meant... so it's at least not a duplicate question

Comment: Some of the terminology in the question is different. The underlying question is almost as close a duplicate as I've seen.

Comment: @CustomizedName No, I understood what you meant _which makes this an exact duplicate_. You still haven’t given any reason that there is **anything** in this question that isn’t precisely the same as in the other question. Nothing. It’s not only a duplicate, it’s an _exact_ duplicate, and it should simply be merged with that question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You are the one who is complaining so you should come up with a reason not me... maybe you need couple of days break... Happy weekend :-)

Comment: No, that's not how close-votes work. I voted to close this question as a duplicate, because it's identical to another question. _That_ is my reason. If you don't think that close-vote is warranted, it's up to you to edit the question so as to make it clear _why_ it's not identical to the other question. The fact that you haven't done this shows that you realise that it is actually a duplicate.

Comment: Nope, the reason I didn't edited is because I find the answer below, good bye now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you have two options:

1. Treat it as English and write the code to parse the string (I doubt you'd have to write it in most languages, I'd expect a library function).
2. Treat it as displaying a data field and just label it.  Then you might as well say *timestamp: 19 January 2015 10:53* as you're not writing a real sentence anyway.  Better than *timestamp* would of course be a more specific word like *logged*, *modified*, etc.

I'm afraid to say that you would like the best of both worlds, and there is no best-of-both-worlds solution.

Comment: That sound to me the most appropriate answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would use "on", since that signifies the day, which is more important to know than the time.  "At" is never used for a particular date.  You are correct in saying that the full written or spoken sentence would be "On January 19th (US usage) at 10:53."  Reversing the order does not make a difference: "At 10:53 on January 19th."

Comment: This is a solid answer, but best-practice on EL&U and Stack Exchange sites in general is to back up solid answers with solid references to authoritative sources.

Comment: There's an answer with the exact opposite opinion: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/501599/10332

Answer (score 0):

None.

> **On** 19 January 2015 **at** 10:53
>   **At** 10:53 **on** 19 January 2015
>   
>   19 January 2015, 10:53 hrs