# Preposition "in/on" when referring to a date range

Tags: prepositions, time

This question is different from [On vs At with date and time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182660/on-vs-at-with-date-and-time).

I am trying to write a sentence saying that some conversation happened at a conference "in/on" May 1--6. I am having a hard time choosing the correct preposition. On one hand, it is a more or less small period of time to resemble "on May 1". On the other hand, it is a little "spread around" so that it resembles "in May". Any advice?

Comment: Considering a date _range_, I would think it was more a choice of either "within/between" than "in/on"

Comment: I wouldn't use a preposition at all (*I'll see you May 1–6*), which seems the most natural to me. Or, if you have to use a preposition, since *May 1–6* is read as *May 1 **to** 6*, I would use **from**, which translates to *I'll see you **from** May 1 **to** 6.* In short, I would use neither of the proposed prepositions.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for your answer!